# Changing the interval argument in animation.FuncAnimation in the matplotlib library has unexpected effects

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

I am having a little trouble working with the FuncAnimation function. The most pressing issue is that changing the interval argument from 1 to any value less than one seems to have no effect on the animation at all, meaning that there is a limit to how fast I can run my animation. For example:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, len(y[0])),
                              interval=1, blit=True, init_func=init)
```

runs the same as

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, len(y[0])),
                              interval=0.01, blit=True, init_func=init)
```

Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround using this function?

Another, possibly related problem, is that the function is not acting as I expect it to anyway. Since the docs say that interval gives "Delay between frames in milliseconds. Defaults to 200.", why does doubling the interval from 1 to 2 have very little effect on the speed it runs at? Surely this should cause the animation to take twice as long to play?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: 
In order to reproduce this, you could use the example code found here:
https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html

Set dt = 0.02 and play around with the interval to see the problem.

The only cause I can think of is that the function does not accept values less than 1, though this does not explain the second issue I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `interval` is the timer interval at which new frames are produced. In reality, it may however take longer to produce a frame. This will depend on the figure size, the amount of data to animate etc.  1 millisecond is already quite fast; at least with usual figure sizes you probably don't reach that speed and it might instead e.g. be 1.7 ms. Then changing to 2 ms does not make any significant difference and changing to anything below 1 does not make any difference at all.

Also mind that you cannot observe such high speeds of 1000 fps with your eyes. The limit of what the human brain is capable of observing is a framerate of ~25 to 30 fps. So rather than artificially speeding up the framerate, you may just stick with some 30 ms interval, and instead change the animation through the `frames` argument or within the animating function.

Comment: Excellent answer, this has helped a lot. I am still encountering issues trying to get the animation to work at 'real time', however - if I use the linked example and use dt * 1000 (converting to ms, dt = 0.05 so well above the threshold for an interval that is too small) for the interval, the animation works much slower than real time. Shouldn't this just cause the animation to refresh every dt? Is the delay caused by my misunderstanding or some sort of lag inherent in the code?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. In order to have the example run in "real time" you would set `dt` to the same as `interval`. So if `interval = 25` milliseconds, dt must be `dt=0.025`.

Comment: This is what I have done, the problem is it doesn't even run close to "real time" - it is far slower.

Comment: Mhh, for me it's showing the real time. I.e. the text in the corner says 10 s after 10 seconds.

Comment: That's bad news - what can I do to try and fix this? I don't even know where to begin with finding what's causing mine to run slower.

Comment: What happens if you set `dt=0.4` and `interval = 400`?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: although increasing the interval has improved the tracking of time problem it is far from a permanent solution since the animation is so poor. Should I open a new question trying to work out why it runs slower on my setup, and how to fix that, rather than continuing the discussion in comments?

Comment: Sure, you may first also simplify the code (I mean one does not need to solve a coupled differential equation to solve some issue about timing). The more information you can give about your setup and how you run the code the more likely it is you will then get an answer, but mind that it'll still be hard if noone else can reproduce this.