# Animation using animation.FuncAnimation from matplotlib playing slower than expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, time

From [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404467/changing-the-interval-argument-in-animation-funcanimation-in-the-matplotlib-libr/52405013?noredirect=1#comment91766657_52405013), it transpired that a piece of code was leading to different animations on my PC as it was to another commenter. I have since re-written the code to make it a little simpler, as was suggested:

```
from numpy import sin, cos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# create a time array from 0..100 sampled at 0.05 second steps
dt = 0.025
t = np.arange(0.0, 20, dt)

length =  len(t)

def listmaker(n):
    return [0]*n

th1 = listmaker(length)
th2 = listmaker(length)

#dummy data
for i in range(0,length):
    th1[i] = 0.01*i
    th2[i] = 0.05*i

x1 = sin(th1)
y1 = -cos(th1)

x2 = sin(th2) + x1
y2 = -cos(th2) + y1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
ax.grid()

line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o-', lw=2)
time_template = 'time = %.1fs'
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)


def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line, time_text


def animate(i):
    thisx = [0, x1[i], x2[i]]
    thisy = [0, y1[i], y2[i]]

    line.set_data(thisx, thisy)
    time_text.set_text(time_template % (i*dt))
    return line, time_text

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, length),
                              interval=25, blit=True, init_func=init)

# ani.save('double_pendulum.mp4', fps=15)
plt.show()
```

The issue, as shown in the other thread, is that since the interval (note that the interval argument is in milliseconds, hence the factor of 1000 difference) in the FuncAnimation is the same as the time step dt, the animation should run at "real time" i.e. the time tracker at the top left of the figure should run at the same speed as a normal clock. While this seemed to be the case for the other commenter, it was not the case on my own PC. I am hoping someone else is also able to reproduce the issue, so I can be pointed in the right direction.

I have no idea what is relevant, but I am running this code on Python 3.7, Idle 3.6.6 on a Windows machine.